# Cannot insert Item to listview

Tags: c#

[Here are all my classes.](http://imageshack.us/f/641/shit2.png/)

MainForm = listview,

CustomerFrame = textboxes

When I compile my program, my `MainForm` appears with an empty listview, and when I press on the add button to insert an item, my `CustomerFrame` class appears. When writing in the textboxes and clicking ok, no item inserted in my listview (`MainForm`). Why?

Some code:

*MainForm*

```
using(var customerframe = new CustomerFrame())
{   
    if (customerframe.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) 
    {
        CustomerFiles.Contact contact = customerframe.GetContact();
        CustomerFiles.Address address = customerframe.GetAddress();
        CustomerFiles.Phone phone = customerframe.GetPhone();
        CustomerFiles.Email email = customerframe.GetEmail();

        //Items in my listview
        listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.FirstName);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.LastName);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(phone.Home);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(phone.Mobile);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.Country);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.ZipCode);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.City);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.Street);
        listviewitem.SubItems.Add(email.Personal);

        this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);

    }
}
```

*MainForm*

```
private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    customerframe.Show();
    CustomerManager cm = new CustomerManager();
}
```

*CustomerFrame*

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MainForm main = new MainForm();
    DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;        
}
```

By the way, when I use

```
 if (customerframe.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
```

this will make the `CustomerFrame` form appear before the `MainForm` (which I don't want) and it will insert item, but only once.

Comment: Looks to me like a scope problem. Do step by step debugging and see the listview contents after it exists adding methods/classes.

Comment: i have done that over and over, and i think the problem is either " using(var customerframe = new CustomerFrame())
{   
    if (customerframe.DialogResult == DialogResult.OK) 
    {" this line or this line "this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you open ANOTHER main form from DialogBox? I think that you should remove this line.

```
MainForm main = new MainForm();
```

And add this

```
DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
Close();
```

Argh, to simplify - code in ButtonOK should look like this:

```
private void btnOk_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
   Close();    
}
```

EDIT: response to new problem

First create new CustomerFrame, show it and wait for it to close; then transfer new data to your ListView. I believe that your add handler should look like this:

```
private void addToolStripMenuItem_Click_1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using(var customerframe = new CustomerFrame())
    {   
        // I don't know what this line does
        CustomerManager cm = new CustomerManager();

        if (customerFrame.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK) 
        {
            CustomerFiles.Contact contact = customerframe.GetContact();
            CustomerFiles.Address address = customerframe.GetAddress();
            CustomerFiles.Phone phone = customerframe.GetPhone();
            CustomerFiles.Email email = customerframe.GetEmail();

            //Items in my listview
            listviewitem = new ListViewItem();
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.FirstName);
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(contact.LastName);
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(phone.Home);
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(phone.Mobile);
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.Country);
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.ZipCode);
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.City);
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(address.Street);
            listviewitem.SubItems.Add(email.Personal);

            this.listView1.Items.Add(listviewitem);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i have fixed that, i have still the same problem, it can not insert a second time :/

Comment: I have had trouble with this for very long time, and you solved it for me.I didnt know the problem was this. Thank you very much

Comment: I am glad I was able to help. From my experience, you can never look directly at the problem - it's kind of hidebehind :-)